# Build a container image from inside a cloud function

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

Context: I am training a very similar model per bigquery dataset in Google Vertex AI, but I want to have a custom training image for each existing dataset (in Google BigQuery). In that sense, I need to programatically build a custom Docker Image in the container registry on demand. My idea was to have a Google Cloud Function do it, being triggered by PubSub topic with information regarding which dataset I want to build the training container for. So naturally, the function will write the Dockerfile and pertinent scripts to a /tmp folder within Cloud Functions (the only writable place as per my knowledge). However, when I try to actually build the container within this script, apparently, it doesn't find the /tmp folder or its contents, even though they are there (checked with logging operations).

The troubling code so far:

```py
def build_container(dataset=str):

    with open('container_template/Dockerfile','r') as f:
        dockerfile = f.read()
    dockerfile = dockerfile.replace('@dataset',dataset)
    f.close()

    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname('/tmp/script-location'), exist_ok=True)

    with open('/tmp/Dockerfile','w') as docker_config:
        docker_config.write(dockerfile)

    docker_config.close()

    shutil.copy('container_template/script-location/script.py','/tmp/script-location/script.py')

    build_client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()

    build = cloudbuild_v1.Build()

    build.steps = [{'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['build', '-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest','/tmp']},
                    {'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['push', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest']}]  

    build_operation = build_client.create_build(project_id=myprojectid,build=build)

    build_result = build_operation.result()

    logger.info('Build Result: {}'.format(build_result.status))
```

When I check the cloud build logs I get:
Step #0: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /tmp/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Some of the code lines need indent fixing in your question: 5, 6, 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've locally tested building a container image using [Cloud Build Client Python library](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/libraries). It turns out to have the same error even the `Dockerfile` file is existing in current directory:

**error:**

> Step #0: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

**build steps:**

```py
    build_client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()

    build = cloudbuild_v1.Build()

    build.steps = [{'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['build', '-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest','.']},
                    {'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['push', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest']}]  

    build_operation = build_client.create_build(project_id=myprojectid,build=build)

    build_result = build_operation.result()
```

Since it uses the API method I followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/running-builds/start-build-command-line-api#running_builds). You will see the `source` is present in API method. It is the missing key to move forward the problem. In [`StorageSource`](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudbuild/latest/cloudbuild_v1/types.html?highlight=build#google.cloud.devtools.cloudbuild_v1.types.StorageSource), you must to specify the `bucket` and `object_`. You need to compress your source code and upload it in Cloud Storage bucket. For example:

1. Run the following command to compress your source code:

```
tar -cvzf sourcecode.tar.gz .
```

2. Upload to Cloud Storage bucket(you can use Cloud Build bucket):

```
gsutil cp sourcecode.tar.gz gs://myproject_cloudbuild
```

3. **build.source**:

```py
    build_client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()

    build = cloudbuild_v1.Build()
    
    build.source = {"storage_source":{"bucket":"myproject_cloudbuild", "object_":"gs://myproject_cloudbuild/sourcecode.tar.gz"}}

    build.steps = [{'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['build', '-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest','.']},
                    {'name':'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
                    'args':['push', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/imagename:latest']}]  

    build_operation = build_client.create_build(project_id=myprojectid,build=build)

    build_result = build_operation.result()
```

As a result it solved the problem building an image using Client Library. I recommended to do all of this inside your Cloud Function.